# The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React.js and I'm trying to learn from the tutorials on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/index.htm) but I faced error. Here is the error on console when I execute npm start command:

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\reactApp1> npm start
> reactapp1@1.0.0 start C:\Users\HP\Desktop\reactApp1.
> webpack-dev-server --hot

The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli. 
Please install .webpack-cli. in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D 
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D 
module.js:540
    throw err; 

Error: Cannot find module .webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs. 
    at Function.Module._resolveFilenam (module.js:538:15) 
    at Function.Module. load (module.j5:668:25) 
    at Module.require (module.js,587.17) 
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18) 
    at Object•<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\reactApp1\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1) 

    at Module. compile (module.js:663:30) 
    at Object.Module. extensions. .js (module.js:656:10) 
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32) 
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:699:12) 
    at Function.Module. load (modul.js:691:3) 
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
  npm ERR! errno 1 
  npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script. 
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     C:Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-06T05_29_08_833Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```
     {
      "name": "reactapp1",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "webpack": "^4.0.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.3"
      }
    }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path:'./',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8090
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello World!!!
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "app"></div>
<script src = "index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just downgrade to webpack 3 using npm install --save-dev webpack@3.10.0

Answer (score 18):

I went through the same example and faced the same issue. So following the above answers I first ran this command -

```
npm install -g webpack-cli --save-dev
```

Nothing happened and was still facing the same issue.

Then I ran this command -

```
npm install webpack-cli --save-dev
```

The issue was solved but I was getting another error.

[image]

Turns out in the new Webpack version they have changed the module attributes also. So you need to make change in the webpack.config.js file also.

```js
module: {
        rules: [
          {
             test: /\.jsx?$/,
             exclude: /node_modules/,
             loader: 'babel-loader',
             query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
             }
          }
        ]
   }
```

So basically **loaders** is replaced by **rules** inside the **module** object.

I made this change and it worked for me.

[image]

Hope it helps other people who are following this tutorial.

To resolve the `Invalid configuration object` issue, I referred to this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482079/5892553

Comment: If I remember correctly, wouldn't doing `-g` will install the package globally and ignore any `--save` or `--save-dev` flags? That might be why your first command there didn't work

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day!!

Answer (score 15):

In webpack 3, webpack itself and the CLI for it used to be in the same package, but in version 4, they've separated the two to manage each of them better.

To solve your issue, install the webpack-cli package as the error suggests by running `npm install webpack-cli --save-dev` on the command line, same as you would any other package.

Comment: Are you running the command with the current directory set to your project folder?

Comment: Installed cli and webpack(npm install -g webpack)...still getting the same error,I am in my project folder...

Comment: webpack and webpack-cli _both_ have to be installed locally, at their latest versions.

Comment: @prakashkumar have you gotten it to work yet? I have the same problem

Answer (score 6):

Was having the same problem, and no luck with the above solutions - I tried installing webpack-cli globally as well as locally and this worked.

```
npm install -g webpack-cli --save-dev
```

This fixed it for me. At least enough to perform `webpack --mode development.`

Comment: So why did this work... if someone can tell me, would help :) my thoughts... I'd started with npm init to start a package in my local project. I'd installed webpack here AS WELL AS GLOBALLY per some video I was watching. When installing globally, this told the command line that this was the webpack I'd be referencing. However, when I installed webpack-cli, I never installed globally. So when searching for it, it was looking in global node-modules. Right?

Answer (score 3):

**Step1:** First run

```
npm i webpack webpack-dev-server webpack-cli --save-dev
```

**Step2:** Loaders are replaced with rules so change code in your webpack.config.j. Let's change your webpack.config.js file:

```
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path:'./',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8090
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

**Step3:** Now go to your package.json file and make some changes in your scripts option:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
},
```

**Step4:** Now run

```
npm start
```

in console

Comment: indeed the first installation is what for me let avoid conflict between global webpack version( installed previously) and the local of a new project. Though I see these as a limitation in "webpack" world and will make soon a solution with docker

Answer (score 2):

**Solved for Webpack 4 -  I hope it works for webpack 2 onwards**

Install webpack-cli globally too by using this command

```
npm i -g webpack-cli
```

So in total you need to run two following commands one for local and other for install CLI globally respectively.

```
npm i -D webpack-cli
npm i -g webpack-cli
```

it works for me I hope it will work for you too :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with this.

```
npm i webpack-cli @webpack-cli/init

npx webpack-cli init
```

Hope to help [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5xoX.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need install webpack server, not webpack-cli. Have a look at the 2nd point in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpack-the-confusing-parts-58712f8fcad9).
Try `npm i -g webpack@2.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `webpack-dev-server`, you need to install `webpack` and `webpack-cli` first. `webpack` is a module which store compiler and, `webpack-cli` is command-line-interface to run it. Otherwise, if you prefer `webpack-command`, a much more light-weight version of `webpack-cli`, you may need to install `webpack` and `webpack-serve`!

Answer (score -1):

The error console is simply telling you how to resolve the issue. Seems like `webpack` module is dependent on `webpack-cli` module. To resolve the issue, just run the command `npm install webpack-cli --save`. it would just work fine.

Comment: Really!! Does it gives you the same error? Can you locate `webpack-cli` directory in `node_modules` folder?