# Missing class properties transform react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I know there are many questions/answers out there but none of them seems to help me resolve my issue. I don't understand what is wrong with my setup:
[image]

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'ftux-components.js',
    library: "shared-components",
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['env', 'react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass', 'postcss-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|jpg|png|woff)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react'
    },
    'react-dom': {
      root: 'ReactDOM',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom'
    },
    'styled-components': {
      commonjs: 'styled-components',
      commonjs2: 'styled-components',
      amd: 'styled-components'
    }
  }
};
```

Here's my babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-react-jsx"
    ]
}
```

I tried reordering presets, adding appropriate plugins (transform-class-properties), deleting reinstalling node_modules but nothing seems to help. My npm and node is up-to-date, also tried using [this](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAYjOiAOoCWCA5sPKDMAHYLEDCEAtpK23gBvAFBw4OCKwIwo6HDGgAKMFAhgCASjijx4gujDAoKtRs0BuEWL0B6W3GqtqMaqkxwZqFjfEwAFtQEAHReLHAAvDq-ephBMACSkqwAEhAAbsbACABccGiYBMAANDHiCBAA7qxJUmmZUNl5BUWlenqGtakZWbn57q1lcKBgqOxNcLLoJUM4_sA4ANYAMvEAouBjSH0tM-3ikuisMNx8mIwTAAwxAL5W4jc2Nv5b5wDKvIyBrHSRcEraCIAPmi4gAkMkCBBzsFMBA6EoAOTzTBwxGWGyPG5AA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=Node-8.9&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2) to make sure I included everything I need for babel. Any suggestions?

Comment: which version of webpack?

Comment: @MatheusSilva "webpack": "^3.12.0",

Comment: You need to install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties if not already done so
by using
npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --save-dev

Comment: "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1", it's already installed :(

Answer (score 3):

In your babel loader you're not including the plugin for class properties even though you already have it installed. Try making your loader look like this:

```
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['env', 'react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay I figured it out. I needed to include presets and plugins in the rules array in module object in webpack.config.js:

```
rules: [
    {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
        presets: ['env', 'react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
        plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
    }
    }
]
```

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092291/the-cli-moved-into-a-separate-package-webpack-cli).