# The command moved into a separate package: @webpack-cli/serve

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I looked at and executed almost every single answer on this post:
[The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092291/the-cli-moved-into-a-separate-package-webpack-cli/49092355)
It has not helped.

Allow me to present my case:

So I have developed a container folder, a separate application where I ran `npm init -y` and then installed the following:

`npm install html-webpack-plugin@4.5.0 nodemon webpack@5.3.2 webpack-cli@4.1.0 webpack-dev-server@3.11.0`

Then I went into my `package.json` file and added the start script:

```
{
  "name": "container",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "webpack": "^5.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

When I go to terminal and run `npm start`, this is why I get every single time:

```
➜  container npm start

> container@1.0.0 start /Users/luiscortes/Projects/ecommRS/container
> webpack serve

[webpack-cli] The command moved into a separate package: @webpack-cli/serve

? Would you like to install @webpack-cli/serve? (That will run npm install -D @webpack-cli/serve) (Y/n) › true
```

And yes even if I choose `Y` or `true` and it runs its `npm install -D @webpack-cli/serve`, when I go back to running `npm start` it just gives me the same error over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is an issue with `webpack-cli@4.1.0`. I upgraded to `webpack-cli@4.2.0` and now it works.