# webpack 4.1.1 -> configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'.

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I just updated webpack to `4.1.1` and when I try to run it I get the following error:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:    object { exprContextCritical?,
>   exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?,
>   noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?,
>   unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?,
>   unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?,
>   wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?,
>   strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }    -> Options
>   affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).

`loaders` look like this and worked with `webpack 3.11.0`:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: ['ts-loader'] },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/, use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        },
        { test: /\.(otf|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=./Scripts/dist/[name].[ext]' }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Looked at an example loader for webpack 4.1.1:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/

All I had to do was rename `loaders` to `rules`.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: ['ts-loader'] },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/, use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        },
        { test: /\.(otf|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=./Scripts/dist/[name].[ext]' }
    ]
}
```